# What are the components of and order of their execution in a Corona app?

Tags: events, sdk, coronasdk

I was wondering which of the two handler functions were called first in a Corona app loop:

```
displayObject:addEventListener( "touch", handler1 ) 
Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", handler2 )
```

I could test for it, but wouldnt be ensured that it was consistently that way and that the Ansca guys wouldnt change it. Since I use the "enterframe" event to trigger my game code loop, it would be good to know whether my game code or my UI code runs first.

I then realized that I hadnt found any documentation from Ansca that described the execution loop at all. What else is going on behind the scenes that might be of interest to the coder, and in what order? Does anybody have a reference to some documentation?

Answer (score 2):

Basically  Runtime with enterframe Events run automatically on every change in frames or you can say that it runs every milliseconds.So, Handler2 is called every milliseconds.Now,when you touch the screen your `handler1 function` is called as well as `handler2 function` is called with very little time difference.So, it is very difficult to say which function is being called first.Hope you have understood it.

Comment: Understood. :) I wish however that Ansca would clarify if there was a handling order and what that order was.